# Xamarin.Forms.Mac - WebP.Mac Error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, filenotfoundexception, xamarin.mac

I've got a Xamarin.Forms.Mac App which did compile for months, until some weeks ago where it says now, that the file or assembly WebP.Mac is missing.

[image: Image is better than 1000 words]

This may be because of the latest Xamarin.Forms version (3.1.0.583944) but I'm not sure about that.

Maybe anyone knows a solution for this

PS: I will provide more information as anyone asks for, but because I don't know whats causing this Exceotion, I cannot provide useful ones right one

Comment: Is this a 3rd-party package in your project, ie.  WebP.Touch ?

Comment: No I don‘t think so, at least i haven‘t added this library

Comment: The reason I ask is WebP.Mac.dll is the Xamarin.Mac assembly name for that package...

Comment: I cannot remember ever used this library, and also searching for **WebP** in all Files (also besides Visual Studio) didn't get a result. I will do that again on my Mac later, but there also shouldn't be found something I think. If this library is referenced somehow, there must be a piece of code inside a *sln* file, doesn't it?

Comment: Depends, if it is using project references and something else is referencing it, then that would not show up in a text search like it would if that project was using `project.config`.

Comment: You were completely right, after I installed the nugget package of WebP, the App starts again. Weird, never used/installed this lib before